# R:Cambiar el el carácter matriz por carácter numérico

Tags: r

Estoy realizando un PCA (principal component analysis). El problema está en que parto de una matriz la cual necesito que todas sus columnas tengan un carácter numérico.

Estoy usando esta función para la matriz llamada m.snp_3regionm con 13 columnas y 13 filas.

Esta matriz viene de realizar este proceso:

De un data.frame como este (porque con el que lo hice es bastante grande como para ponerlo aquí):

```
        Position Treatment        Region_name          region_name
           970    Total           Intercistronic.region   5
           970    Convolvulus     Intercistronic.region   5
           970    Non_Convolvulus Intercistronic.region   5
           970    Carduus         Intercistronic.region   5
```

Realicé la matriz con esta función:

```
     snp_3regionm<- acast(snp_IC.region, Region_name+Position ~ Treatment, fill = 0)

         m.snp_3regionm<-snp_3regionm

         m.snp_3regionm[m.snp_3regionm == 5] <- 1
```

E intenté cambiarla a factor numérico con la siguiente función:

```
   m.snp_3regionm[,1:13]<-as.numeric(m.snp_3regionm[,1:13]).
```

También he intentado la función:

```
    m.snp_3regionm[,1:13]<-sapply(m.snp_3regionm[,1:13],as.numeric)
```

y tampoco obtengo caracteres numéricos

aplicando la función str(m.snp_3regionm) obtengo

```
chr [1:13, 1:13] "0" "1" "1" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "1" "0" ...

 attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:13] "3'noncoding.region_1942" "3'noncoding.region_1956" 
"3'noncoding.region_1957" "3'noncoding.region_1986" ...

  ..$ : chr [1:13] "Carduus" "Convolvulus" "Cucumis" "Non_Carduus" ...
```

No se me cambia el carácter por numérico ¿Qué debería de hacer?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Adrián, comparte un `str(m.snp_3regionm)` para saber de que tipo de datos se trata. Saludos

Comment: chr [1:13, 1:13] "0" "1" "1" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "1" "0" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:13] "3'noncoding.region_1942" "3'noncoding.region_1956" "3'noncoding.region_1957" "3'noncoding.region_1986" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:13] "Carduus" "Convolvulus" "Cucumis" "Non_Carduus" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, yo revisaría por que `acast()` retorna una matriz de caracteres, eso ya es una mala señal, o al menos algo que habría que revisar. En cuanto a tu pregunta, ocurre lo siguiente: `as.numeric()` efectivamente convierte los valores de la matriz recibida pero retorna un vector plano (una matriz no deja de ser un vector pero con dimensiones), por ejemplo, simulando algo parecido a tus datos:

```
m.snp_3regionm <- matrix(c("0","1","1","0","1","0","X","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","1"), ncol=4)
m.snp_3regionm

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "0"  "1"  "0"  "0" 
[2,] "1"  "0"  "0"  "0" 
[3,] "1"  "X"  "0"  "1" 
[4,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "1" 

as.numeric(m.snp_3regionm)

 [1]  0  1  1  0  1  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
Warning message:
NAs introducidos por coerción
```

Vemos que el resultado final es un `vector` y el otro tema, es que en el ejemplo forzamos un valor que no puede convertirse a numérico, algo que eventualmente puede estar ocurriendo con tus datos (de ahí que la matriz sea de caracteres). Al convertir obtenemos un Warning, los valores no convertibles se transforman en `NA's`.

Si quiere mantener la naturaleza matricial de los datos, la forma más sencilla es, modificar directamente la clase del objeto:

```
class(m.snp_3regionm) <- "numeric"

Warning message:
In class(m.snp_3regionm) <- "numeric" : NAs introducidos por coerción

m.snp_3regionm

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0
[3,]    1   NA    0    1
[4,]    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: Saludos Patricio, y gracias por tu pronta respuesta. He realizado las funcione que me has dicho. Lo primero que al hacer as.numeric(m.snp_3regionm) obtengo un objeto de carácter numérico pero no es lo que quiero. Obtengo una única columna de de 0 y 1 con 169 filas (supongo que serán todas las columnas juntas en una única). Por lo que no obtengo el mensaje de "Warning message: NAs introducidos por coerción ".  Cuando realizo la función class(m.snp_3regionm) <- "numeric" no me da ningun mensaje de advertencia y no realiza ningún cambio, manteniendose el formato de matriz.

Comment: @AdriánP.L., por empezar `class(m.snp_3regionm)`  es una `matrix`? Por que no pruebas: `apply(m.snp_3regionm[,1:13], 2, as.numeric)`?

Comment: Esa es Patricio, con la función                                                              m.snp_3regionm<- apply(m.snp_3regionm[,1:13], 2, as.numeric obtengo los datos en formato numérico. Muchas gracias!